# Java specify command line argument from 1 to 100

Tags: java, arguments, command, line

In my Java code I want to define integer numbers by the command-line arguments. As below:

```
    int z = Integer.parseInt(args[3])
```

If I define my Program arguments as 0 1 2 3 4 ...
,then by the above I will get integer 3. 
My question is if it is possible to specify/input command-line arguments from 0 to 100 in shorter and smarter way than manually writing 0 1 2 3 4 ... ?

I'm using IntelliJ as IDE and define argument as Run -> Edit Configurations -> Program arguments

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If they are contiguous you could define the upper and lower bounds and then, depending on what you need to do with them, use a loop to assign them to an array instead of variables.

Comment: What manual writing are you referring to? The arguments that you pass from the run configuration oder the `args` indices in your code to access these arguments?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Could you please advise how the upper and lower bounds can be defined in this case?

Comment: As in for example `java MyClass 3 9` which would be used instead of `java MyClass 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, then you just read `args[0]` and `args[1]` create an array with size `args[1] - args[0]` and loop from `args[0]` to `args[1]` and fill that array with 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.